# Что делает .ToArray() и зачем он нужен в данном коде?

Tags: c#, linq

Вот код:

```
string input = "hello world";
string output = new string(input.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray());
```

Здесь я создал переменную `input` и переменную `output`. Я хотел присвоить `output` перевернутое значение `input`, почему без `.ToArray()` код не работает, зачем нужен `.ToArray()` и что он делает я не понял.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Метод `Reverse` (как и большинство остальных методов Linq) возвращает `IEnumerable`, но у класса `String` нет конструктора, принимающего `IEnumerable<char>`, зато есть конструктор, принимающий массив. Метод `ToArray` как раз и собирает массив на основе входной последовательности `IEnumerable`.

[Конструктор String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.string(v=vs.110).aspx)

Кстати, строка реализует `IEnumerable<char>`, поэтому вызывать `Reverse` можно прямо на ней, `ToCharArray` можно не вызывать.

Answer (score 1):

В качестве дополнения в правильному ответу @Андрей NOP, если ваша цель — развернуть строку, вам нужна [более сложная техника](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail/).

Например, вот такой код поддерживает символы из старших плоскостей Unicode, а также ненормализуемые акценты:

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetGraphemeClusters(string s)
{
    var enumerator = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(s);
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        yield return (string)enumerator.Current;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] strings =
    {
        "Les Mise\u0301rables",
        "Co\u0323\u0302ng ho\u0300a xa\u0303 ho\u0323\u0302i chu\u0309 nghi\u0303a Vie\u0323\u0302t Nam",
        ""
    };
    foreach (string input in strings)
    {
        string output = string.Concat(GetGraphemeClusters(input).Reverse().ToArray());
        Debug.WriteLine($"{input} -> {output}");
    }
}
```

(код одолжен [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15111719/276994))